# How to terminate the Elastic Search query when it times out?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my query **HTTP POST**. 
**URL** : http://127.0.0.1:9200/*-2023.02.*/_search?timeout=10ms
**Request** :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "event.code": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "@timestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 10000
}
```

**Response** :

```
{
    "took": 1557,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 984,
        "successful": 984,
        "skipped": 826,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

May I ask why I set the timeout 10ms, but the time spent is 1557ms(took) ? 
How can I set a timeout so that Elastic terminates the query? 
Elastic Search Version 7.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `timeout` parameter is **per shard**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#search-timeout). If the time spent on one shard exceeds the timeout value, then the current search on that shard is cancelled and the hits gathered till then are returned.

As you can see, you have 984 shards, so if you have a single node with a single processor it could **in theory** take up to 9.84 seconds to return with a 10ms timeout. It's probably not your case since the query returned in 1.5 seconds, but that was just to illustrate that the timeout is not working the way you expect it to.

Comment: Ok, I understand that timeout refers to the timeout on the shard. Will there be any error message or prompt when it times out?

Comment: You mean in the ES server logs ?

Comment: HTTP Response or server log, any.

Comment: If the query times out, you'll get `"timed_out": true` in the response

Comment: If the query NOT times out, you'll get `"timed_out": false` in the response ?

Comment: Yes, like in your example above, the query did not time out